# how to call ajax with after loading algolia result?

Tags: magento2, algolia

Magneto Version : 2.3.0
Algolia Version : 1.11.3

I have integrated Aloglia into the M2 site and i need to run ajax call with product SKU after Aloglia results in the product list page.

can you please suggest me how can I call it?

Comment: Please provide some code and explain where the problem is. This would make it more easier to help.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have fixed my way

Comment: That's great. It would be kind if you could post your solution as an answer here for those with the same or a similar problem.

Comment: Using allItems function in algolia instantsearch.js